# Stop route change when resolve returns no data in Angular 5

Tags: angular

How to stop routing when resolve service returns empty records? I want to stop the route change depend on resolve data. Please check below code.

route config -

```
{
  path: 'search',
  component: SomeComponent,
  resolve: { searchData: SomeResolveService }
}
```

**some.resolve.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeResolveService implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private someService: SomeService) { }
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    return this.someService.search(somedata);
  }
}
```

**some.service.ts**

```
search(somedata): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .post(`${environment.apiPrefix}/search`, somedata);
}
```

The above service response returns below json -

```
{
   records: [], 
   totalRecordsCount: 0
}
```

I want to stop route change when the totalRecordsCount is 0 and show the same view.

Comment: You're not routing anything here. Please post the code reliative to your routing.

Answer (score 2):

One Solution is Tapping into the `Observable` using RXJS Utility Operator **[tap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html)** and re-navigating based on some condition.

> The RxJS tap operator looks at the observable values, does
>   something with those values, and passes them along. The `tap` call back
>   doesn't touch the values themselves.

**Example**

```
    @Injectable()
    export class SomeResolveService implements Resolve<any> {
      constructor(private someService: SomeService,Private route:router) { }
      resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> {
        return this.someService.search(somedata).pipe(tap((response)=>{
                  //you could use some logic to check your totalRecordsCount  here                 
                       let total= //some logic to extract totalRecordsCount
                        if(!total)
                           {
                             this.route.naviagte[('/yourRoute')]
                           }});

                         }
```

**[`LIVE DEMO USING tap`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4laaqu)**
Or you could use RXJS `map` operator to Intercept the response and re-navigate based on some condition.
Though this operator is used to modify the response before sending it to the application I don't see any harm in using it for this purpose.
**Example**

```
 @Injectable()
    export class SomeResolveService implements Resolve<any> {
      constructor(private someService: SomeService,Private route:router) { }
      resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> {
        return this.someService.search(somedata).pipe(map((response)=>{
                  //you could use some logic to check your totalRecordsCount  here                 
                       let total= //some logic to extract totalRecordsCount
                        if(!total)
                           {

                             this.route.naviagte[('/yourRoute')];
                                return null;

                           }
                      return response;
                       });

                         }
```

**[`LIVE DEMO USING map`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6l2bur?file=src%2Fapp%2Fresolve.ts)**

Comment: Hi, If the provided answer has solved your question please consider accepting it